# When does a matrix $A$ with ones on and above the diagonal have $\det(A)=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

What conditions, if they're even necessary, must be placed on $\star$ so that the matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & & \huge{1} \\ & \ddots & \\ \huge{\star} & & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $$

so that $\det{(A)}=1$, where $\huge{1}$ denotes "all entries above the diagonal are $1$'s," and $\huge{\star}$ is just some arbitrary scalar entries from a general field $F$? My intuition tells me that that no matter what it's $1$.

### EDIT:

More specifically, disregard my call for conditions, but assume rather that the lower diagonal entries are $\color{red}{\text{guaranteed to be less than $1$}}$.

Comment: The determinant is 0 if all the stars have the value 1 (assuming the matrix has at least two rows).

Comment: You think the matrix of all ones
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
has determinant 1?

Comment: Well, if this matrix is symmetric then it's singular and $\det (A) = 0$

Comment: Would you please read the descriptions of the tags before you add them? I don't see how this has *anything* to do with algebraic topology and the abstract-algebra tag is only barely applicable here.

Comment: @kahen I just like the idea that mathematics spills over.

Comment: OK, how about this: I know that the lower diagonal entries are definitely less than $1$.

Comment: Algebraic topology tag appearing in this question was kind of funny.

Comment: @Trancot: Mathematics is interconnected. However, that does not mean that *anything* is connected to *anything else*. If and when you see an actual connection to algebraic topology, explain that connection in your post and feel free to add the tag *then*.

Comment: I bet I could come up with something. I think that you should consider thinking that all things are connected. Consider Grigori's use of fluid flow over an object to show something about the object itself.

Comment: It's not about being creative though, it's about helping people find questions they are interested in / can answer / have confusion about.

Comment: I see. Is there such a creative web source?

Comment: In the $2\times 2$ case, $\det \pmatrix{1&1\\ t&1}=1-t$ takes every value in $(0,+\infty)$ when $t$ ranges over $(-\infty,1)$. For only one of these values, you get $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & & &\huge{1} \\ a_1 & \ddots \\ & \ddots & \ddots \\ \huge{\star}& & a_{n-1} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ be your matrix. I claim that $\det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-a_i)$.

To see why this is true, note that by expanding the determinant in the first column, we get $$\det(A) = \begin{vmatrix}1 & & &\huge{1} \\ a_2 & \ddots \\ & \ddots & \ddots \\ \huge{\star}& & a_{n-1} & 1\end{vmatrix} - a_1\begin{vmatrix}1 & & &\huge{1} \\ a_2 & \ddots \\ & \ddots & \ddots \\ \huge{\star}& & a_{n-1} & 1\end{vmatrix}+0+0+\cdots+0,$$
since the first two rows are equal except for their first entries.

Hence $\det(A) = (1-a_1)\begin{vmatrix}1 & & &\huge{1} \\ a_2 & \ddots \\ & \ddots & \ddots \\ \huge{\star}& & a_{n-1} & 1\end{vmatrix}$ and we get our result by induction.

Thus the restriction you are looking for is $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (1-a_i) = 1$, where $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ is the lower diagonal of your matrix.